# How to configure GeoServer user/roles using programmatic way?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, geoserver-security

I am working on GeoServer 2.15 on CentOS and configuring users/role manually.
We have 300 layers,10 workspaces & 25 users, created 3 roles (internal, external & classified). I want to assign each role to every workspace and its associated layers.

Manually it's possible, but I am looking at a programmatic way to do this thing.

I am aware its possible using [REST interface](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/geofence-server/rest-userrole.html) and curl commands (ultimately its updating that xml file only), so is this a proper way ? Or do I have to write Python code using [gsconfig](https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/rest/python_gsconfig.html) for this thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolutely any program that is capable of requesting and sending XML or JSON files to and from the REST API endpoints. So `curl` or `gsconfig` are fine choices, so is `PostMan` or you can write something in Python, Java, RUST, Go etc. Whatever you feel most comforable in.